# Mayúsculas y Minúsculas en INPUT PHP

Tags: php, condiciones, else

estoy practicando en PHP un ejercicio que me solicita ingresar "Hola" en un INPUT y como resultado salga un mensaje indicando "Muy buenas, usuario". Caso contrario, si pongo "Adiós", un mensaje me indica "Hasta luego".

Lo desarrollé de la siguiente forma:

```
<form method=POST>
      <input type="text" name="saludo"></input>
      <button type="submit">Resultado"</button>
</form>

<?php

$mensaje = $_POST['saludo'];

if($mensaje == 'Hola'){
      echo "Muy buenas, usuario";
   }else if($mensaje == 'Adiós'){
      echo "Hasta luego";
   }else{
      echo "Complete de manera correcta lo solicitado";
   }
?>
```

Hasta acá todo bien. Lo que quiero saber es cómo puedo hacer de manera eficiente un ingreso de datos que reconozca la expresión "Hola" cuando el usuario ingresa (por ejemplo): HOLA - HoLa - hOlA - HOLa - etc. Lo mismo con Adiós: AdiÓS - ADIós - ADIOS (incluso con o sin acento).
La idea es ingresar esos datos de manera correcta pero tambien apropósito datos casi similares al solicitado. 
Incluso se me ocurre usar switch, pero termina siendo engorroso si lo tengo que aplicar en varios formularios.

Dichos de otra forma:

Lo que quiero hacer es contrario a: "Ingrese Hola" -> en el INPUT: Hola -> sale "Muy buenas, usuario". Lo que quiero hacer es: "Ingrese Hola" -> en el INPUT(de manera errónea): "HoLa" -> sale "Muy buenas, usuario".

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

1) Crear diccionario (que estoy investigando como armar) Ó 2) Un ejemplo engorroso:

```
if($mensaje == 'Hola' || $mensaje == 'HoLa' || $mensaje == 'hOlA' || etc ){
  echo "Muy buenas, usuario";
}
```

Comment: si el problema es solo mayuscula o minuscala cambialo todo a mayuscula ejemplo `if(strtoupper($mensaje) == "HOLA"){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no de problemas las mayúsculas o minúsculas agrega esta validación.

Donde en las condiciones convierte el mensaje en minúsculas para poder ser evaluado tal cual el texto que esta estas comparando.

```
if(strtolower($mensaje) === "hola"){
   echo "Muy buenas, usuario";
}else if(strtolower($mensaje) === 'adios'){
      echo "Hasta luego";
}else{
      echo "Complete de manera correcta lo solicitado";
}
```

Comment: Por favor considera explicar tu código, ya que este debe ser comprensible no solo para quien lo publica sino para el resto de la comunidad que en algún momento consulte esta respuesta